# what is the image set under this linear map?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a linear map with $f(0)=0$ then the set $$\{f(x_1,\dots,x_n):\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j^2\le 1\}$$ equals

$1.$ $[-a,a]$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R},a\ge 0$

$2.$ $[0,a]$ for some $a\ge 0$

$3.$ $[0,1]$

$4.$ $[a,b]$

Linear map $\Rightarrow$ Continuos so image of a compact set will be compact but what more I can say?

Thank you for help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296837/f-colon-mathbb-rn-rightarrow-mathbb-r-be-a-linear-map-with-f0-0-0-ldots?rq=1  my question can be closed as it is exact duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The image must be symmetric about $0$ since if $f(\vec x) = k$ then $f(-\vec x) = -k$.

Comment: Depending on the quantification on $b$ in $4.$, it might (also) be a possible answer.

Comment: @GitGud: I didn't want to imply that any of the options were the correct one because the question has either been badly set or badly asked.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing you. I was just pointing out the possibility. I figured it was better to do it on your answer than on the question.

Comment: $[-a,a]$ will be the correct answer?

Comment: @Tsotsi: Probably. It depends whether #4 gives any further conditions on $a$ and $b$. [This is the problem with multiple-choice questions.]